# Two types of criticality

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings, graph-minors, hadwiger-conjecture

Suppose $G$ is a finite simple graph. Let $h(G)$ denote the *Hadwiger number* (synonym: *connected pseudoachromatic number*, cf. [Abrams-Berman 2014, p. 315]) of $G$; that is, the maximum $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $K_n$ is a [minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_minor) of $G$.

> Is there a non-complete graph $G_0$ with at least $3$ vertices and with the following two properties?
>
> 1. whenever you remove a vertex, the chromatic number gets decreased (that is, $G$ is *vertex-critical*, to use an established term), and
> 2. whenever you identify two non-adjacent vertices, $h(\cdot)$ gets increased. (We could call graphs with this property "*identification-critical*"; I do not know of an established terminology).

**References**

[Abrams-Berman 2014] Lowell Abrams, Yosef Berman, ''Connected pseudoachromatic index of complete graphs'', Australasian Journal of Combinatorics, Volume 60(3) (2014), 314-324

Comment: The article you link doesn't define vertex-criticality.

Comment: Was the -1 vote due to the bad wording of the original post before the edit, or is there an easy example to what I am asking?

Comment: I suppose you want $G_0$ to have at least $3$ vertices.

Comment: Dear @ Dominic van der Zypen: under the hypothesis that the leaving out of the usual technical term was not your intention, I proactively added the usual technical term, and a few things more (noted in the log of the edit). This considerably improves the question, by putting it into the proper context within the recent research literature.

Comment: I shied away from a more invasive edit: to replace ''collapse 2 non-adjacent vertices'' with 'identify two non-adjacent vertices'. The latter I would recommend, because (0) the verb 'collapse' is not usually used with respect to vertices, (1) two use a numeral ('2') for such a statement is not considered good style: in a sense, the number need hardly be emphasized here, for to identify two vertices. Would you mind that edit?

Comment: Thanks @PeterHeinig, your edits and contributions are always very welcome! I will make the changes you mention in your most recent comment.

Comment: That's right @Dap, will ask for non-complete graphs