# Increasing the Hadwiger number by identifying non-adjacent points

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-minors

This is a specialization of a more general, still unanswered [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/289501/two-types-of-criticality).

Suppose $G$ is a finite, simple graph. Let $h(G)$ denote the *Hadwiger number*, that is, the maximum $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $K_n$ is a [minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_minor) of $G$.

Is there a non-complete graph $G_0$ with at least $3$ vertices and the property that whenever two non-adjacent vertices are identified, $h(\cdot)$ gets increased?