# Effect of collapsing independent sets on the Hadwiger number

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a connected, finite, simple, undirected, and non-complete graph $G=(V,E)$ such that whenever an [independent subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)) $J\subseteq V$ with $|J|>1$ is collapsed, the [Hadwiger number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger_number) of the resulting graph is larger than the Hadwiger number $\eta(G)$ of $G$?

**EDIT.** Excluded complete graphs; thanks to Ilya Bogdanov for his comment below.

Comment: A complete graph works vacuously.

Comment: Thanks - will exclude this in the question!

Comment: Such a graph would also yield a positive answer to this question of yours https://mathoverflow.net/questions/290435/increasing-the-hadwiger-number-by-identifying-non-adjacent-points (same question of existence, with a *weaker* condition), so better stay with the other one first. BTW I would intuitively think that both are equivalent, but that might be a different question!